# Terminator layout with command that survives sigkill?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminator, sigkill

Terminator allows custom layouts with a command such as `bash -lc 'npm start'; bash`

However, triggering SIGKILL (CONTROL-C) will kill part of the terminal and mess up your layout. SIGQUIT works but that's hard to remember. Is there a way to have a layout with a bash command that drops into a bash interactive terminal after SIGKILL, instead of having to use SIGQUIT?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a .bashrc hack. If configure terminator to open one terminal in say, `~/git/proj1` and another in `~/git/proj2`, I can check the pwd and run commands that way. For node projects this may be enough

```
if [ -f "$(pwd)/package.json" ]; then
  git pull
  npm start
fi
```

Or more generally

```
if [ "$(pwd)" == "/" ]; then
  echo "you are root!"
fi
```